# Updating Mysql table data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
$updateSeats = mysql_query("UPDATE FORM_dateAndSeating SET NumberOfSeats = " . $removeSeatingNumber . " WHERE DATE = " . $revertToStandardDate);
```

In the code above I am trying to update the value within the MYSQL table.
When I `echo` the variables they show the data I am expecting, however the database is not being updated.

There is no error being returned either.

What are other possibilities for the sql not to update properly??

Comment: Are you sure no errors are occurring? Check `mysql_error()`. Is your `WHERE` clause actually finding something to update?

Comment: It is important to mention `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Anyway, what does `mysql_error()` show you?

Comment: Try `$updateSeats = mysql_query("UPDATE FORM_dateAndSeating SET NumberOfSeats = '" . $removeSeatingNumber . "' WHERE DATE = '" . $revertToStandardDate . "'");`

Comment: fred your answer worked:-) if you want the points post it as an answer:-)

Comment: @JeffKranenburg Glad to hear it Jeff. Posted, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$updateSeats = mysql_query("UPDATE FORM_dateAndSeating 
SET NumberOfSeats = '" . $removeSeatingNumber . "' 
WHERE DATE = '" . $revertToStandardDate . "'");
```

Long form:

```
$updateSeats = mysql_query("UPDATE FORM_dateAndSeating SET NumberOfSeats = '" . $removeSeatingNumber . "' WHERE DATE = '" . $revertToStandardDate . "'");
```

The variables need to be inside double quotes including single quotes

I.e.: `'" . $removeSeatingNumber . "' WHERE DATE = '" . $revertToStandardDate . "'`
-------^ --------------------------------------------^ -----------------------^ ----------------------------------------------^

Answer (score 0):

Add apostrophes around your column values.